# design infrastructure use case for eCommerce website

Tags: e-commerce

we have given an assignment to find all the technical details about a website of our choice.

the parameters that we are suppose to search are
1. framework
2. hosting provider
3. email client etc.

for ex. if I choose amazon then

how many or what type of servers does amazon use?
what framework does amazon have?
if possible what is the location of these servers?
who is the dns provider?
 etc

I searched online but could not find nuch useful information. It seems that none of the sites that I chise disclose this information (which looks pretty obvious). but then how shall I find these technical details about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its funny i didn't know about this tool but your post inspired me to do some searching and i found this: 
https://wappalyzer.com/

its a free add-on for firefox or chrome browser. its not going to tell you everything but i just did a test on an e-commerce site and it identified it as Magento e-commerce. applications etc they say they can detect

https://wappalyzer.com/applications